# unity The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem that when i change scenes from the menu to the game and when i click i will get the error 'The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.' and this is happening while the menucontroller is not in the game scene, i have been working on this for the past few days to fix it but cant find how to do it. If anyone can help that would be great this kind of question has been asked alot but I cant find a solution for my problem.

We also have a similar script that has the same code except instead of sceneswitching its for interaction so when we try to interact with something we get the error

Thank you for your help.

menucontroller

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using API;

public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private InputActionReference shoot;
    [SerializeField] private InputActionReference shoot2;
    public GameObject sendObject;
    public GameObject sendObject2;
    public float range = 1000;




    void Start()
    {
        shoot.action.performed += Shoot;

       
    }

    async void Shoot(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(sendObject.transform.position, sendObject.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are way too much lines of code. Reduce your code sample to the buggy part and tell us what line your error occurs, rather than throwing all your code and let us digging ourself

Comment: I reduced the code now it is better to understand

Answer (score 2):

The error message sounds quite self-explanatory.

You are trying to access an object that already was destroyed.

Since you load a new scene

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
```

the current scene and its objects are unloaded / destroyed.

Whenever you deal with events

```
void Start()
{
    shoot.action.performed += Shoot;
}
```

make sure to also remove the callback as soon as not needed/valid anymore

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    shoot.action.performed -= Shoot;
}
```